# How to increase upload size for phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not an administrator so I only have read access to the php.ini file and I cannot move files to the phpmyadmin directory. Also I cannot use the command line mysql as the system mysql has been stopped. How do I resolve this problem? I need to upload files as large as 4 GB.

Comment: You cannot unless you modify the php.ini file.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with PhpMyAdmin if the MySQL server is down? Or is it that the `mysql` *client* has been disabled?

Comment: can you describe the system in general so we can think about how usage works? I am trying to think of any reason somebody needs a 4gb upload.

Comment: Well, its a huge data file. I'm trying to import data into tables that are really large in size.

Comment: I changed the ini file so now the max size is 8000 MB but I still get the error saying the upload size is too big. In the actual GUI it says max size: 8000 Mi

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done unless you modify the `PHP.ini` file, and even then I wouldn't upload 4GB files (even if its a local upload).  That type of SQL file upload/mount should be done via command line / GUI on the server IMHO.

An alternative would be using a client to manage the SQL DB, not phpmyadmin.

Take a look at [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for instance.

Comment: +1 for suggesting HeidiSQL & suggesting to upload SQL files through command line.

Comment: It sounds like this user is on shared hosting. So linkinkg to HeidiSQL seems sort of pointless.  Of course your suggestion is valid.  Its just unlikely even an option for the user, who does not even have administrator of the MySQL installation.

Comment: The MYSQL client has been disabled so I can't do anything through command line

Comment: @cool_cs - **So have the administrator of the server enable it for you.**

Comment: @cool_cs, you might be in a position where you have SSH access, and can SSH tunnel HeidiSQL into your shared host to access your remote mysql host. Again I'm making assumptions here as I don't know your setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have access to change settings then there is not allot you can do.

There is a great little tool written in php, to help you import large .sql files called [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) it will stagger the import process.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of stuff that you have to see:

1. **PHP CONFIG** you have to edit the php max upload file size to be able do it with you PHP I think that by default it's like 2 MB (not sure) change it for a big value if you need it. But WAIT, there is more...
2. **NOT REPONSE**:If the File is Really BIG, and the server is slow, it's probable that the client close the connection for uploading a file without receiving any signal, for this issue An ajax is the Really recommended (like a upload progressbar).
3. **MySQL Set UP** And Finally, you have to see your DB field type and size. make sure yourself that the Data type in your Mysql will be able to storage the file size.